# Applescript (10.6.8). how to start app from user input

Tags: macos, list, input, applescript

I am developing an automated test for several Mac OSX apps with applescript. The app should do the following.

1.) Display dialog shows up, where the user can type in 1 or more app names he want to be tested for example (1.test.app, 2.autotest.app,....)

2.)depending on how many apps names he has typed in, the apps should start and close consecutively to check if they are working.

So for example if the user type in apptest1.app, apptest2.app, apptest3.app -> the first app starting should be apptest1.app and then close it, the next app should be apptest2.app start and close and so on.

thank you very much.

lg,

San

Comment: What is your question ? And what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
tell application "Finder"
    set thePath to path to applications folder
    set theApps to get name of every file of thePath
    set apps_to_test to choose from list (theApps) with multiple selections allowed
end tell

repeat with the_app in apps_to_test
    tell application the_app
        activate
        quit saving no
    end tell
end repeat
```